# Magento 2.2.5: How to get something (students,teachers,products) by id

Tags: magento2.2, factory

i'm doing update "students" on magento 2.2.5
and i'm stuck in `how to get student data by id`
i saw they use repository to load by id, but when i come in this file

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\ProductRepository.php
```

they using factory to load by id
[image: C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\ProductRepository.php]

here is my students table in mysql:

[image]
but with what i search for, the load() method in factory is cant be use anymore.
so i wanna ask how to `how to get student data by id`

my code for now:

```
<?php

namespace Fudu\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Student;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Fudu\HelloWorld\Model\StudentsFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;


class Update extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var StudentsFactory
     */
    protected $studentsFactory;

   public function __construct(
       Action\Context $context,
       StudentsFactory $studentsFactory
   )
   {
       $this->studentsFactory = $studentsFactory;
       parent::__construct($context);
   }

/**
 * Load Student data by given Student Id
 *
 * @return $student
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 */

public function execute()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $student = $this->studentsFactory->create();
    $student->load($id);
    return $student;
}
}
```

Comment: as per your question you need to use Join for getting students data from your products.

Comment: sorry i dont follow , can u explain it more clearly

Comment: could you please give your students table detail so i can explain you more in detail.

Comment: oh okay, i have update it on my post , please take a look, and thanks for reading my post

Comment: in your table where is the product id ?

Comment: i dont have it, i only have students id, which is "id"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80431/discussion-between-dharmendra-jadav-and-fudu).

Comment: $student->load( $id , 'id' );
Try adding field

Comment: @MandarParbate oh hello, i'm looking for another way to do this, i already did this successfully by using factory, but like i said, the load() is deprecated now, but its still work, but i thing we have to find another way soon, because in the next update, magento 2 will remove that load() and we cant use that anymore

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
<?php

namespace Fudu\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Student;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Fudu\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Student\CollectionFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;


class Update extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var StudentsFactory
     */
    protected $studentsFactory;

   public function __construct(
       Action\Context $context,
       \Fudu\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Student\CollectionFactory $studentsFactory
   )
   {
       $this->studentsFactory = $studentsFactory;
       parent::__construct($context);
   }

/**
 * Load Student data by given Student Id
 *
 * @return $student
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 */

public function execute()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $student = $this->studentsFactory->create();
    $student->load($id);
    return $student;
}
}
```

I have made function in helper for demo.
Please use as per your need.

Or you use this.

```
$students = $objectManager->create('<vendor>\<module>\Model\ResourceModel\Student\Collection')->addFieldToFilter('<your_id>', 1);
```

Please do not use object manager create instant of your collection. I have giving just example for getting data by id.

Comment: but what about the return ?
and u still use the factory as i said on the post.
i dont want to use the factory,because it deprecated

Comment: objectmanager is recommended not to use for now

Comment: You can use model directly  ( \<vendor>\<module\Model\Student $_students) if you not use factory

Comment: well, i'm following you with factory, but it throw an error:
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid return type

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid return type
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#3 {main}

Comment: i put my code on the post, please take a look, thanks you

Comment: Try my updated code

Comment: it throw this
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `students` AS `main_table`1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid return type

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Invalid return type
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#3 {main}

Comment: i already did delete gerenation folder and clear cache with 
php bin/magento cache:clear